# How to use IntelliJ's Evaluate Expression tool with lambdas and outer scopes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

Here is a simple Java 8 lambda example.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String outerScope = "outer";
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String runnableInner = "runnable inner";
                System.out.println("inside runnable: " + outerScope);
                Void avoid = null; //Breakpoint
            }
        };
        Runnable lambda = () -> {
            String lambdaInner = "lambda inner";
            System.out.println("inside lambda: " + outerScope);
            Void avoid = null; //Breakpoint
        };
        runnable.run();
        lambda.run();
    }
}
```

Inside the `runnable` scope it's possible to use IntelliJ's "Evaluate Expression" tool to evaluate that `outerScope` is defined.

However, inside the `lambda` scope `outerScope` is undefined.

Both print statements correctly print the value of `outerscope`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126257#u=1407007602744. Apparently it is caused by some JDK bug (assuming that it's the same case as the one you describe, which it seems that it is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda expressions are compiled into synthetic methods within the owning class. When I run `javap -private -l` with your class, this method is printed as:

```
private static void lambda$main$0(java.lang.String);
  LineNumberTable:
    line 18: 0
    line 19: 3
    line 20: 28
    line 21: 30
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        3      28     1 lambdaInner   Ljava/lang/String;
       30       1     2 avoid   Ljava/lang/Void;
```

What you can see here, is that the method has a parameter which will receive the actual captured value for the `outerScope` variable. But the `LocalVariableTable` does not declare a name for it which is most likely the reason why the debugger doesn’t show its runtime value.

Ironically, this means that if we remove the `LocalVariableTable` attribute, we will see the desired value. E.g. when compiling with `-g:lines` and stopping at a breakpoint within the lambda expression body, the `Netbeans` debugger shows:

```
args    String  "outer"
Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option
```

So we know see all values passed as parameter at the cost of not seeing the other local variables declared inside the method.

---

So what’s needed, is a `LocalVariableTable` attribute containing the names of the outer scope’s variable names for captured values, an issue which has to be fixed in `javac` which will [apparently happen in jdk1.8u60](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054220).

If you can’t wait and don’t want to write a tool patching the `LocalVariableTable` attribute you may consider that the *caller* of the synthetic method knows the parameter values. So if you go one step upwards in the stack trace to the runtime generated lambda instance, you will see all captured values as instance variables though they will have generated names like `arg$1` etc.